# SSE2 instruction to typecast an integer register to short register and vice-versa

Tags: x86, sse, simd, sse2

Is there any SSE2 instruction to typecast an integer register to short register and vice-versa? Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "typecast" exactly, but if you are looking for a narrowing operation then you can use `_mm_packs_epi32` (`PACKSSDW`) to pack two integer vectors to one short vector:

```
__m128i vint1, vint2;  // 2 vectors of 4 x 32 bit ints
__m128i vshort;        // 1 vector of 8 x 16 bit ints

vshort = _mm_packs_epi32 (vint1, vint2);
```

The reverse, widening (unpacking) operation can be achieved like this:

```
 vint1 = _mm_srai_epi32(_mm_unpacklo_epi16(vshort, vshort), 16); // PUNPCKLWD+PSRAD
 vint2 = _mm_srai_epi32(_mm_unpackhi_epi16(vshort, vshort), 16); // PUNPCKHWD+PSRAD
```

Note that there is no automatic sign extension when using SSE unpack instructions, hence the need for the arithmetic shift when signed values are being widened.

Comment: I mean exactly what you have pointed out.
But is it possible to do the reverse i.e.expanding 1 vector of 8 X 16 bit ints into 2 vectors of 4 X 32 bit ints, one having the lower 4 short values and the other having the higher ones.

Comment: Yes, there are widening operations too - I'll add an example. Again, I suggest getting the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-intrinsics-guide) which will answer your questions much more quickly and definitively than I can.